# cannot get two equivalent OWLClasses in OWLAPI using reasoner

Tags: java, owl-api

I am new Semantic web. I am trying to parse the Ontology but facing difficulty in examining how to know two OWLClasses are equivalent to each other.

Like using reasoner, OWLApi give different methods to extract information, example: for subclasses we can use this.reasoner.getSubClasses(). Same way is there any way I can get to know if i have two classes ClassA and Class B, they are equivalent. I am using OWLAPI in java.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OWLReasoner.isEntailed()` and pass as argument an `OWLAxiom` created using `OWLDataFactory.getOWLEquivalentClasses(A, B)` where A and B are your classes.